# how to drop columns in PostgreSQL if column begins with a specific pattern

Tags: postgresql, ddl

drop  columns in PostgreSQL, if column name  begins with a specific pattern

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  address character varying(500),
  primaryemailid character varying(150),
  trial577 character(1));


CREATE TABLE public.table2
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  address character varying(500),
  salary character varying(150),
  trial389 character(1));
```

like this i have multiple tables with trial  name
how to delete that column name 
Am using  below command but facing error

```
ALTER TABLE public.alarmconfig DROP COLUMN  LIKE 'trial%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the information schema to determine all tables and columns:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE schema_name = 'public' AND column_name LIKE 'trial%';
```

You can use it to get the necessary statements as a list:

```
SELECT FORMAT('ALTER TABLE public.%s DROP COLUMN %s;', table_name, column_name) 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE schema_name = 'public' AND column_name LIKE 'trial%';
```

Finally, you can copy and paste these statements into `psql`.

If this is a recurring task, you can write a stored function based on the query above.